# How to wait in java without stopping the entire program

Tags: java, logic

I am making a game where the player can throw up to three projectiles at a time. I'm having trouble with the reloading. Here is the code:

```
public class AmmoManager {
public void tick(){
    if(Player.ammo <= 0){
        for(int t = 0; t < 10; t ++){

        }

        Player.ammo = 3;
    }
}
```

}

It's supposed to wait a bit and then set the ammo to 3, but as soon as the ammo becomes 0, it is set to 3 instantly. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using sleep, but the entire application would stop.

Comment: Use multi threading. Thread.sleep(time_in_milisec)

Comment: I think a better option in this sort of programming is to manually implement a timer.  When the ammo first becomes 0, set a timer equal to `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  Then on each tick check if the desired time has elapsed.  When it has, allow the reload.

Comment: Do I use the Timer class?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your main program waits for tick() to return something.

Think about it like this; if you have this method

```
public boolean isOne(int num){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(num==1){return true;}
    return false;
}
```

and

```
boolean result = isOne(1);
if(result){ //can't be ran until isOne(1) returns the boolean
    //do something
}
```

You can't continue with you main class when you call isOne() because you dont have the value of the boolean it returns. you have to wait for it to return the value, and then you can continue with the main method

The solution is threading. I'm not an expert on it, so you will need to consult someone else or an online resource, but I think it would look something like this:

```
public void tick(){
    new Thread({ new Runnable(){
      @Override
       public void run(){
         if(Player.ammo <= 0){
             Thread.sleep(*seconds* times 1000);
             Player.ammo = 3;
          }
        }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

> as soon as the ammo becomes 0, it is set to 3 instantly. What am I doing wrong?

That's because the `for` loop does nothing. When you enter `tick()` and `Player.ammo` is `0`, you instantly set it to `3`.

> I've tried using sleep, but the entire application would stop.

If you only have one thread, that is what `Thread.sleep` does.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you are attempting is more difficult than you think...

You need a main loop that controls the pace of the game. I might sleep() to ensure that the game does not run too fast.

Each pass, it must instruct every player, or whatever constructs you use, to update themselves. As one of the comments noted, that might involve incrementing a counter to replenish ammo.